# Deleting customer addresses in magento

Tags: magento

I need to delete customer addresses programmatically, but I didn't find a function to do that.

```
 $recordedAddresses = array();
    foreach ($customer->getAddresses() as $address)
     {
        $recordedAddresses = $address->toArray();
     }
```

I already took the addresses' collection as showed above, I just wanna delete them by id.
Curiously I didn't find examples but using API.
Could someone gimme a hand with that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at the Mage_Customer_AddressController controller class and deleteAction() method.  Essentially all you need to is load the address by it's id:

`$address = Mage::getModel('customer/address')->load($addressId);`

and then delete it:

`$address->delete();`

`delete()` is a standard method you can run against all models (see `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract`), you can also set the `_isDeleted` flag and call `save()` which will have the same result.

Answer (score 6):

Somehow Magento keeps empty entities after using `$address->delete()` in my case. There were empty addresses on account preventing admin from saving the customer form when using this method.

Only way I've found to actually remove the address from user account is by changing the protected $_isDeleted flag to true:

`$address = Mage::getModel('customer/address')->load($addressId);
$address->isDeleted(true);`

Hope it saves some time for anyone who will stumble uppon same Magento behaviour.

Comment: Great. Thank you.