# Delete customer address in single query

Tags: magento

Is there any way to delete customer addresses in a single query.

I know we can fetch customer address object and delete one by one record in the loop but it's a very time-consuming process so I want to delete customer addresses in a single query.

For example, customer id is "1234" and the customer has 15 addresses.

I am very new in Magento and I have not cleared Magento 1 database structure so please help me how can I delete customer addresses in a single query in Magento 1.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below url, customer adresses delete with addressid.

[Deleting customer addresses in magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15341997/deleting-customer-addresses-in-magento)